# How to do auto login with siege/curl on a React.js app

Tags: reactjs, curl

I can't use curl to do a form submission for a React site, http://www.fingage.com. Any idea how I can script this or modify the site such that automated login with a command line tool is possible?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Did you try something like this? `curl 'https://www.fingage.com:9370/login/auth' -H 'Host: www.fingage.com:9370' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Referer: https://www.fingage.com/auth/login' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Origin: https://www.fingage.com' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data '{"email":"test","password":"test"}'`

Comment: Ok that certainly works-- although I get back the resonse of the back-end API that is used by the frontend. How would I then construct a request to navigate to a logged in page after this?

Comment: Depending on the exact details the following might work. This is how I got the above: Open Firefox/Chome's DevTools, go to the Network tab, log in and navigate to where you want to go. Then right click on the request you're interested in and find the option to `Copy as cURL`. Then paste into a text editor where you're writing your script. Repeat for other requests in the Network tab. There could be things you need to parse out of the returned data to include in subsequent requests, but `Copy as cURL` is probably a good starting point.